# AWS Glue ETL MongoDB Connection String Error

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

Issue using MongoDb with AWS glue - I've created a connection to the database (using the MongoDb connection option) and run a crawler against it and it all worked fine, but when I try to use this as a datasource in a basic ETL job (script- Glue version    2.0Python version   3) it throws the exception

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.getDynamicFrame.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Mongo/DocumentDB connection URL is not supported

Has anyone had any success using MongoDb as a datasource in glue ETL jobs?

Comment: Did you ever get that to work in the end?